# Have examples of non-simple connected higher-dimensions integer homology sphere?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, kt.k-theory-and-homology

We known that there exists smooth integer homology n-sphere (n>4) with some non-trivial fundamental group by the Kervaire theorem [*Michel A. Kervaire*, MR 253347 [**Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=253347), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **144** (1969), 67--72.]

---

(1) Have another examples about that?
 (2)  Is it possible that  some aspherical manifolds are  higher-dimensions  integer homology spheres?---Asked by Thurston and Kan.

---

Remark:  As far as I know, Andrejz Szczepanski [Aspherical manifolds with the Q-homology of a sphere] proved (2) in the odd dimensions, but it is the rationnal homology sphere. And it is also true in the 3-dimension and 4-dimension, see [*John G. Ratcliffe and Steven T. Tschantz*, MR 2114711 [**Some examples of aspherical 4-manifolds that are homology 4-spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.top.2004.10.006), *Topology* **44** (2005), no. 2, 341--350.]

Comment: In (1) it is not clear what you mean by "realize". The construction of Kervaire is quite explicit as far as these things go. Regarding (2) I think the existence pf aspherical homology spheres is an open problem in any dimension $>4$.

Comment: Regarding the edited version of (1) a general method of building cutom made homology spheres in higher dimensions is developed in [Hausmann, Jean-Claude, Manifolds with a given homology and fundamental group. Comment. Math. Helv. 53 (1978), no. 1, 113–134.] The method is surgery theoretic, and generalises Kevaire's work.

Comment: A conjecture of Hopf is that for closed aspherical
manifolds $M$ of dimension $2k$, $(-1)^k \chi(M) \geq 0$. This conjecture implies that a manifold of dimension $4k+2$ could not be a homology sphere. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture

Comment: ^ of course, I meant that an aspherical manifold of dimension $4k+2$ could not be a homology sphere if the Hopf conjecture holds.