# Homology sphere with $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the universal cover

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

> **Question.** *Is there a $3$-dimensional integer homology sphere whose universal cover is $\mathbb{R}^3$?*

I believe the answer is in the positive and I am looking for (precise) references. If not in dimension $3$, I would be happy with higher dimensional examples.

This question is related to my post: [Linking topological spheres](https://mathoverflow.net/q/294953/121665) and also to the post [Have examples of non-simple connected higher-dimensions integer homology sphere?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/247502/121665) (This link was provided by Ian Agol).

Comment: Yes: an integral homology 3-sphere that admits a hyperbolic metric.  These are fairly easy to construct, but I'm on a train right now, so I can't post a precise reference to one of the constructions (this is why this is a comment rather than an answer).

Comment: Related question in higher dimensional case: https://mathoverflow.net/q/247502/1345

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a sense, most $3$-manifolds have universal cover $R^3$. In particular, this is the case for hyperbolic $3$-manifolds. And there do exist integer homology spheres which are hyperbolic. Two explicit examples I found by googling:
[Auckly: Surgery numbers of 3-manifolds: a hyperbolic example](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~dav/surno.pdf) and
[Hom, Lidman: Surgery obstructions and hyperbolic integer homology spheres](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2018-146-03/S0002-9939-2017-13925-2/home.html).
It should be possible to get more examples from [SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/#).

Comment: If you tell me your name (you can e-mail me) I will put you in the acknowledgements since I will use this result in a paper.

Answer (score 13):

In fact, this is true for any closed connected 3-manifold with aspherical fundamental group. More generally, the [universal cover of a closed 3-manifold](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public/public_html/cover?preview=cover20.gif) is $S^3$ punctured at $0, 1, 2$  points or a tame Cantor set.

Aspherical homology spheres abound, for example $1/n$ surgery on a knot for $n$ sufficiently large. Other examples are [Brieskorn spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) $\Sigma(p,q,r)$ with $p,q,r$ pairwise relatively prime and $1/p+1/q+1/r \leq 1$.

Comment: Your first link seems to take me to a dropbox page with no associated pdf.

Comment: @MikeMiller there should be a gif, it’s a slide from a talk I gave. Are you logged in to dropbox?

Comment: I get the notice: "The folder ‘/Public/public_html/cover’ doesn’t exist." It seems that your link doesn't include any user data so I am not sure it should link to one of your files. (I am mostly just curious about the argument!)

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. I found a link to the slide [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cxdm5tu5hsnho0i/AAA3VNNzJZiEkl3F8bkHgxMIa/cover?dl=0&preview=cover20.gif&subfolder_nav_tracking=1) following through your webpage.

Answer (score 10):

There are several good answers but I thought I'd chuck in one more. Prior to all of the important results on geometrization mentioned above, Waldhausen had shown that any Haken manifold (any 2-sphere bounds a ball and the manifold contains an incompressible surface) has universal cover $\mathbb{R}^3$. Simple examples of Haken homology spheres are obtained by gluing two non-trivial knot complements in such a way that meridian and longitude are interchanged.

Piotr also asked about higher dimensional examples. These are harder to come by. In dimension $4$ there is "Some examples of aspherical 4-manifolds that are homology 4-spheres" by Ratcliffe and Tschantz, Topology Volume 44, Issue 2, March 2005, Pages 341-350. I don't know about dimensions higher than that.

Comment: I added a comment above about a related question in the higher dimensional case. https://mathoverflow.net/q/247502/1345

Answer (score 4):

Here are two references which also might be of help:

The introduction of

*Saveliev, Nikolai*, Invariants for Homology 3-spheres, Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences, 140. Springer (2002).

has a description and construction of Seifert Fibered Homology Spheres with infinite fundamental group, $\S$1.1.4 in the 2002 edition. (I have yet to read the 2013 edition.) Also, Peter Scott's paper:

*Scott, Peter*, [**The geometries of 3-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/blms/15.5.401), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 15, 401-487 (1983). [ZBL0561.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0561.57001).

could then serve as a reference for the fact that the universal cover of a Seifert fibered homology sphere with infinite fundamental group has $R^3$ as a universal cover. Here I am relying on the complete classification of orientable $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ manifolds (see p. 457-459 of Scott's paper).